# multiples updates con mysql y php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo el siguiente inconveniente, necesito actualizar varios el valor de un campo en varios registros pero si se cumple la condicion. Seria como un while dentro del if.. les adjunto el codigo sql. En la consulta3 obtengo valores y luego SI el número de registros es mayor a 0 quisiera actualizar con el bucle while todos los registros que cumplen la condición No recuerdo como debe ser. Desde ya muchas gracias..

```
$consulta3 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT comp_sal  FROM salidas where comp_sal = '$comp' and id_user <> '$id_user'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($consulta3) > 0) {

    $sentencia2 = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE salidas SET comp_sal ='$comp' + 1 as sal where id_user= '$id_user' and DATE_FORMAT(salidas.date_sal,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') like '$date_sal'");

    $result2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $codigo2 = $consulta2['sal'];

}elseif (mysqli_num_rows($consulta3)==0) {


$consulta4 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT comp_sal as sal FROM salidas where id_user = '$id_user'  order by salidas.comp_sal DESC LIMIT 1");
  $consulta5 = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta4,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $codigo2 = $consulta5['sal'];
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes concatenar tus query de updates y al finalizar el ciclo ejecutarlos.

ejemplo:

```
$query="";
while(){//tu ciclo
  $query.="UPDATE salidas SET comp_sal ='$comp' + 1 as sal where id_user= '$id_user' and DATE_FORMAT(salidas.date_sal,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') like '$date_sal';";
}
if($query!=""){
  $sentencia2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
  $result2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $codigo2 = $consulta2['sal'];
}
```

Espero haber comprendido tu pregunta

Comment: Hola Juan, no entiendo donde obtengo la respuesta del if (si existen valores que cumplen la condicion) ?Gracias

Comment: Perdón, voy a aclarar porque yo no soy bueno explicando... quisiera saber como sería la estructura utilizando un bucle for o foreach  para actualizar si se cumple la condicion del If que me dice si existen registros con esa condicion...